# Clear raw HTML from malicious data in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xss

I'm writing ASP.NET MVC app. Some pieces of HTML comes from user and some of them from third-party sources. Is there easy and fast enough way to clean HTML without heavy artillery like HAP(Html Agility Pack) or Tidy?

I'm just need to remove scripts, styles, `<object>/<embed>`, `href="javascript:"`, `style=`, `onclick` and I'm not think that removing them manually via .Remove/.Replace is a good way even with StringBuilder.

In example, if I have next input

```
<html>
    <style src="http://harmyourpage.com"/>
    <script src="http://killyourdog.com"/>
    <div>
        <a href="http://co.com">Good link</a>
        <a href="javascript::harm()">Bad link</a>
        <p>Some text <b>to</b> test</p><br/>
        <h1 style="position:absolute;">Damage your layout</h1>
        And an image there <img src="http://co.com/a.jpg"/><br>
        <span onclick="harm()">Good span with bad attribute</span>
        <object>Your lovely java can be there</object>
    </div>
</html>
```

which must be converted into next:

```
<div>
    <a href="http://co.com">Good link</a>
    <a>Bad link</a>
    <p>Some text <b>to</b> test</p><br/>
    <h1>Damage your layout</h1>
    And an image there <img src="http://co.com/a.jpg"/><br>
    <span>Good span with bad attribute</span>
</div>
```

So, how to do this — with whitelist of tags and anttributes — in right way?

UPD: I'm tried StackExchange HtmlHelpers library, but it removes needed tags such as `div`, `a` and `img`.

Comment: Why do you allow HTML from user input in any case?

Comment: You may want to ban end-user HTML input and either use a markdown language or some kind of encoding, not just raw input.

Answer (score 1):

Fastest way to achieve the same is to use Regular Expression

```
var regex = new Regex(
   "(\\<script(.+?)\\</script\\>)|(\\<style(.+?)\\</style\\>)|(\\<object(.+?)\\</object\\>)", 
   RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
);

string ouput = regex.Replace(input, "");
```

You can also use Microsoft Web Protection Library (http://wpl.codeplex.com/) for same like

```
Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(input);
```